# Is it possible to replicate the Windows 7 'show desktop' behaviour in Mac?

Tags: macos, desktop

I'm fairly new to Mac. In Windows 7 I can easily show the desktop by clicking at the far right bottom corner of the Windows Task Bar. I would like to do the same thing in macOS.

Is it possible for me to do this?

**NOTE** - I already know I can use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd> keys  or the <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> keys to do this. What I want is to click on the bottom right of the Dock to show my desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest to what you want is to use the Hot Corners feature of macOS. More specifically:

1. Go to **Apple > System Preferences...**
2. Select the **Desktop & Screen Saver** preference pane
3. Click on the **Screen Saver** tab
4. Click on the <kbd>Hot Corners...</kbd> button
5. Now choose the "Desktop" option from the drop-down menu for the bottom right Hot Corner
6. Exit System Preferences

Now all you need to do is move your mouse pointer to the bottom right corner and your Desktop will appear (no need to click like you do in Windows).